# Adding a UILabel as a subview on top of a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a fake placeholder for a `UITextView` with a `UILabel`. Let's say there's a `UITextView` inside `ViewController` and this is what I do:

```
    CGFloat frameWidth = self.postInputField.frame.size.width;
    textViewPlaceholder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, 200)];
    textViewPlaceholder.text = POST_PLACEHOLDER;
    textViewPlaceholder.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:textViewPlaceholder];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

And there's an unnecessary margin on top of the UILabel as shown below:

[image]

I could set the `y` value to be negative something but I want to make sure why this is happening. One thing that I do when the view controller is loaded is `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` to get rid of the margin inside the `UITextView`, but it shouldn't matter.

The exact x y values that work are `(4, -16)` for the UILabel.

Comment: y r u adding the placeholder to self.view? Isnt it supposed to be self.yourtextview ?

Comment: I tried your way and there is no margin!!! Try giving the constraints to your textview

Comment: if I add it to self.myTextView I get even more margin. Not sure what's happening..

Comment: I applied constraints to the textview and there is no margin

Comment: what constraints did you apply?

Comment: just height and width and top and bottom. But if you have other views, then you shouldnt give height and width, just give leading,trailing,top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the height of `UILabel`:

`textViewPlaceholder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, 200)];`

The height is too large. Try to reduce it. And using background color to see more.